# Spatial bookmarks missing from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, bookmarks

I just converted to QGIS 3 (3.4.4). My Spatial Bookmarks panel is empty.

Is there something I need to do to get them?

Comment: Do you still have the previous version of QGIS which contained the bookmarks?

Comment: I was using 2.18, which appears to still be on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, QGIS 3 asked me at first start whether it should adopt settings from QGIS 2 or I wish a clean QGIS 3 start. Not unlikely, that your bookmarks might have been converted via adopting settings from QGIS 2.

The other way is (or as least should be...) exporting your bookmarks in QGIS 2 and re-importing them in QGIS 3 this way:

[image]

I just tried that, but it seems just to work little buggy and incomplete (Note that I dont't know whether export or import is the problem here...):

QGIS 2 bookmarks:

[image]

Error during import in QGIS 3 (click OK):

[image]

QGIS 3 bookmarks:

[image]

Comment: QGIS 3 did not ask me any questions like it did you ("whether it should adopt settings from QGIS 2 or I wish a clean QGIS 3 start". However, the export/import thing seems to have worked fine!